# jQuery Plugin Not Available in Ember Component

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I have a component that uses a jQuery plugin to format numbers. This is the plugin: https://github.com/asual/jquery-format

I include the plugin in my Brocfile (using ember-cli)

```
app.import('vendor/jquery.format-1.3.min.js');
```

In my component I can successfully access my component like:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  var formattedNum = $.format.number(val, '###,###.##');
  this.set('val', formattNum');
}
```

However, I keep getting warnings from the ember (jshint) that it doesn't recognize the '$' variable.  I believe the proper way of access the underlying jQuery variable is doing the following:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  var formattedNum = this.$.format.number(val, '###,###.##');
  this.set('val', formattNum');
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, I always receive the error: 'Cannot read property 'number' of undefined.  Is this a different way to access this plugin method?  I've tried this.$().format.number(..) and this.$.format.number(...).  Both fail.

Andrew

Comment: it sounds like you need to specify that $ will be a global in your jshint preferences

Comment: yeah, that would probably get rid of the warning... aside from that, shouldn't I be able to access my jQuery plugins from the Ember supplied this.$ variable?

Comment: Hint: Add a debugger statement between var formattedNum and this.set()...   Log 'this' to the console. Is it the element you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a computed function instead of using didInsertElement. You should get item before publishing into your page, and format the number fields of item. For example, try this in your component.js:

```
formatSomething : Ember.computed('item', function () {
    this.set('item.val', this.$.format.number(this.get('item.val'), '###,###.##'));
}),
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to access it with `window.$` instead of `this.$`.

`this.$` is going to call it on the object to which `didInsertElement` belongs (which is probably your component)

Comment: sadly, from a JSLint perspective, the 'window' variable isn't defined in the code either.  I believe it's only inserted by the browser once it's run.